# Change QGIS 3 shortcut keys for layout view / print composer

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, shortcuts

I wanted to change the keyboard shortcuts in the QGIS 3 layout view / print composer, but I cannot find any buttons from this section, for example: "New layout - Ctrl + N".

How to change it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Ctrl + N` is assigned to `New` for New Project, you cannot assign the same shortcut key to an existing one. You need to create another shortcut for the `New` before using `Ctrl + N` for new layout.

Comment: @ahmadhanb What about other keys / buttons? I can't even find them in the key list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible, see this feature [request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/41610).

Answer (score 3):

If you like, you can create a new layout using N instead of `Ctrl + N` as it is reserved for creating New QGIS project. To do that:

- Go to `Settings -> Keyboard shortcuts`

[image]

- Search for New print layout
- Click on `Change` button
- Press letter `n` on your keyboard and it will be changed to `N`
- Then close the window.

Go to `Project -> New print layout`, and you will find the shortcut will become `N`

[image]

Press letter `n` (small letter), and the New print layout will pop-up:

[image]

To see all the shortcuts, expand the `Keyboard shortcuts`, and you will se all the assigned shortcuts:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I can change the keyboard shortcuts for the `New Print Layout` action. But the problem is that I don't see any actions available in layout view (layout view / print composer) in the list of available keyboard shortcuts. Can you find any of these actions in this list: `Preview Atlas` (shortcut `Ctrl + Alt + \ `) or `Export Atlas as Images` or `Layout Properties`?

Comment: The commands in your screenshots do not belong to layout mode (layout view / print composer).